# .GPS program code shows no error but 'unfortunately application stopped ' message coming on emulator . Please help me out

Tags: android, gps, android-manifest

GPS program code shows no error but `unfortunately application stopped` message coming on emulator.
My GPS code for WhereAmI.java .

```
package com.example.whereami;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import com.marakana.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WhereAmI extends Activity implements LocationListener { //
LocationManager locationManager; //
Geocoder geocoder; //
TextView textOut; //

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOut);
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE); //
geocoder = new Geocoder(this); //
// Initialize with the last known location
Location lastLocation = locationManager
.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER); //
if (lastLocation != null)
onLocationChanged(lastLocation);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() { //
super.onRestart();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
10, this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() { //
super.onPause();
locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

//Called when location has changed
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { //
String text = String.format(
"Lat:\t %f\nLong:\t %f\nAlt:\t %f\nBearing:\t %f", location
.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), location.getAltitude(),
location.getBearing()); //
textOut.setText(text);
//Perform geocoding for this location
try {
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10); //
for (Address address : addresses) {
textOut.append("\n" + address.getAddressLine(0)); //
}
} catch (IOException e) {
Log.e("WhereAmI", "Couldn't get Geocoder data", e);
}
}
//Methods required by LocationListener
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```

My manifest file : AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.marakana" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
<activity android:name=".WhereAmI" android:label="@string/app_name">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
<!-- -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

my main.xml file : it also is error free

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff" android:orientation="vertical">
<!-- -->
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textColor="#333" android:textSize="30dp" android:text="@string/hello_world"/>
<!-- -->
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<!-- -->
<TextView android:textColor="#333" android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" android:textSize="25dp" android:text="Waiting..."
android:id="@+id/textOut"></TextView>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat errors for the above programfor which i am getting the message 'unfortunately application stopped ':

```
   12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3350 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3350 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-23 10:04:43.288: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641): null
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cd3350 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-23 10:04:43.309: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641): Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce41c8 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce41c8 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-23 10:04:43.318: E/ActivityThread(641):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641): null
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641): android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40ce41c8 that was originally bound here
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:969)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
12-23 10:04:43.338: E/StrictMode(641):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: i posted it above @323go

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You manifest showing

```
 Package = "com.marakana"
```

In your class (whereami) the package that you declared is "com.example.whereami;"

Change package name in manifest ("com.example.whereami") from ("com.marakana")

Try this manifest after removing "import com.marakana.R;" from your imports

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.whereami"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="4"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.whereami.WhereAmI"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>



     </activity>
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> 


</application>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes i tried changing the package name but now the emulator has stopped working  before changing it used to work though @rahul kapoor

Comment: When i remove the import i get R.layout.main and R.id.textout error  @rahul kapoor

Comment: Yes i restarted eclipse after removing the imports but get the same R errors

Comment: even after cleaning i get the same errror please kindly send me the complete code so i can check properly

Comment: Now the program is running on my mobile but i am not getting the gps and "Waiting" message is coming on the screen ..

Comment: When i run the above code i again get the message "application unexpectedly closed" and it's not running . Can you provide some more help. Thanks

Comment: please can You give me an idea as to how to include gps so that i get my location . If Some small changes in the code might help then can you tell them . Thankss

Comment: Yes I saw it. it gave location using maps.But i want in terms of latitude and longitude i.e. gps

Comment: can you give the complete code to find latitude and longitude without using google api and maps .Since Google api is not woring properly . I saw the links you gave me.I don't need that much of info of a place like given there . I just need the latitude and longitude .Can you help me out . Thankss

Comment: Check this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/ .